# Is it OK to pass around EF Entities in MVC3 ViewModels and not incur performance issue due to lazy loading?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, viewmodel

I want to pass around an EF entity in a property of an View Model, but I am worried that it could incur performance issues since some of the column values of the DB records are big. I then realised that unless I access those particular fields then I would not incur that penalty due to lazy loading. Is this correct?

So to elaborate, in the below example the book property may be called ABSTRACT which is a STRING which is VARCHAR(MAX) in the DB. It may also have ID, AUTHOR and TITLE:

```
   public class vmTest
   {
   public Book MyBook { get; set; }
   }
```

If I only wished to access ID and TITLE then if my theory is correct then the ABSTRACT column will not be loaded into RAM and therefore cause no performance issues.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the moment you ask for MyBook, all ints, strings will be loaded from the database. Lazy loading works only with referenced entities.

This actually the ideal situation for ViewModel. Create ViewModel and load it only with data you need. So in controller:

```
var toView = context.Books.Select(e => new YourViewModel { BookID = e.ID, Title = e.Title}).SingleOrDefault(vm => YourFilter(vm));

public class YourViewModel
{
    public int BookID { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set;}
}
```

Doing so, you load only data you need as the select statement will do appropriate projection in db.